# JavaScript implementation problem with Apache tomcat

Tags: javascript, apache, tomcat

I work in a networking environment, so my knowledge of programming in javascript is very limited. I've been trying to get the error in this VoIP system applied to a call center. So far, I just have the logs of what happened, but it's more than 5k lines so I will just paste what I think it's causing the problem.

The architecture is like this:

Our solution (javascript form that changes call center receivers status to available /not available) -----> Apache tomcat catalina <-------- a server provided by **altitude** that gives the final form for the call center receivers

After changing campaigns (only on one user, but then the rest got desyncronized real quick) on our form, everything stopped working and we had to restart the tomcat. Excuse my poor knowledge of programming, but this is what I got from the logs:

**at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)**

```js
2018-11-27 12:04:53,003 http-bio-8585-exec-5 INFO    throw
altitude.integrationServer.exceptions.ISException {Code=InvalidOperation, Message=Invalid operation!}
 at altitude.integrationServer.javaApi.ExceptionsConverter.ISExceptionToExceptions(ExceptionsConverter.java:89)
 at altitude.integrationServer.javaApi.AgentInCampaign.open(AgentInCampaign.java:909)
 at controller.AgenteAltitud.abrirCampaya(AgenteAltitud.java:459)
 at controller.AltitudController.abrirCampanya(AltitudController.java:180)
 at boundary.AltitudBoundary.abrirCamapanya(AltitudBoundary.java:139)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleSimpleCORS(CorsFilter.java:323)
 at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:169)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If someone's able to give me a bit more information, thank you very much.

Comment: Java is not the same as Javascript

Comment: Tomcat is a Java application server, and that error message is a Java stack trace

Comment: Contact altitude - my guess is that you're passing an incorrect parameter from  the front end (which *is* JavaScript) to the back end.